# Is it possible to delete localstorage item on window close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-cookies

I'm storing the UTM parameters on first-time user lands into the website. He/She can visit any page of the website and during signup, I'm sending these parameters to the backend(storing to the database).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href.match('utm_*')) {
        var utmData =  {
        utm_source: getParameterByName('utm_source'),
        utm_medium: getParameterByName('utm_medium'),
        utm_campaign: getParameterByName('utm_campaign'),
        gclid: getParameterByName('gclid')
        }
        if(!localStorage.getItem('utmData')) {
            localStorage.setItem('utmData', JSON.stringify(utmData));
        }else if(localStorage.getItem('utmData')){
            localStorage.removeItem('utmData');
            localStorage.setItem('utmData', JSON.stringify(utmData));
        }                           
    }
});
```

But the problem is When the user not signup but these parameters are still there. I want to remove when he/she close the browser.

Comment: why don't you use SessionStorage instead of localStorage if you do not want the items to persist?

Comment: Can you Please give the answer about the same, How to implement that @AakashThakur

Comment: The very purpose of LocalStorage is to persist data across page reloads. If you don't want this data persisted, why are you using LocalStorage in the first place?

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, I did wrong on first place. Session storage was the correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want items to persist, you can save the data in `SessionStorage`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href.match('utm_*')) {
        var utmData =  {
        utm_source: getParameterByName('utm_source'),
        utm_medium: getParameterByName('utm_medium'),
        utm_campaign: getParameterByName('utm_campaign'),
        gclid: getParameterByName('gclid')
        }
        if(!sessionStorage.getItem('utmData')) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('utmData', JSON.stringify(utmData));
        }else if(SessionStorage.getItem('utmData')){
            sessionStorage.removeItem('utmData');
            sessionStorage.setItem('utmData', JSON.stringify(utmData));
        }                           
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, It is sessionStorage, not SessionStorage.

Answer (score 3):

Use [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) handler.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  localStorage.removeItem('utmData');
  // return nothing for no «quit confirmation»
};
```

Comment: Be careful with using that API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload if the user will be using mobile check to ensure it supports it

Comment: @Nico, What's wrong with it, when no quit confirmation required?

Comment: @vp_arth when I redirect to another page it is removing from local storage. That won't help

Comment: support for mobile safari

Comment: Then I didn't understand the question at all. How redirect differs with close?

Comment: Ah, I see, `close window` in title; But close browser in the question body.. Use sessonStorage.

Comment: Yeah that exactly i want @vp_arth

Comment: just replace all `localStorage` with [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) Their interfaces are equal